# how to create modular UI units (components) in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Let's assume we need to create simple UI component for our Rails app, for example header. We'll start by creating multiple files:

1) `app/views/partials/_header.erb`

2) `app/assets/stylesheets/_header.scss`

3) `app/assets/javascript/_header.js`

and after that we need to include those in proper views or manifest files.

**Question:**

Is there an easy way to move this files to a single folder? For example:

```
app
|-- ui_components
|   |-- header
|   |   |-- view.erb
|   |   |-- style.scss
|   |   |-- script.js
```

And, in case of `.scss`, include them in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` by doing:

```
@import "ui_components/header/style"
@import "ui_components/footer/style"
...
```

Same for `.js`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Component support, and bundling assets is still limited out of the box.

I managed to get it working with the **cells Gem**

```
gem "cells-rails"
```

The cells gem allows you to put view components in `app/cells`, see http://trailblazer.to/gems/cells/

In your `application.rb` you need

```
def self.cells_with_assets
  all_cell_file_names = Dir.glob("app/cells/**/*.rb")
  all_cell_file_names.map do |f|
    f.match(/app\/cells\/([a-z_\/]*)\.rb/)[1].classify
  end
end    

config.cells.with_assets = Application.cells_with_assets
```

To make it work with SCSS you also need to make sure, the files from there are included, so in your `application.scss` do:

```
/* Include all SCSS Files in the cells directory
*= require_tree ../../cells
*/
```

Of course I would recommend using `ActionView::Component` now, since it is now parts of the rails core, since 5.x (not sure).

https://github.com/github/actionview-component

Comment: I hope this helps you, I will hopefully be able to update this answer with a pure `Actionview::Component` answer

Comment: thanks. will give `Actionview::Component` a try soon

Answer (score 0):

The concept of bundling css, html and js together is often used in javascript frameworks such as vuejs, where the three 'languages' can be included in a "single-file-component".

I realize that this is not exactly what you are asking, but since you have expressed a desire to bundle css/html/js, you may wish to consider vuejs single file components. They are eminently reusable across the whole app, carrying their own styles and behaviours.